# How to change file permission for all users in R

Tags: r, chmod

When I use `Sys.chmod(file,'777')` it looks like the permission is changed only for the owner and not for all users, how can I do this ?

Comment: What permision does the user who is running the script / code have?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Disable the umask check in `Sys.chmod` to get what you want:

```
Sys.chmod(file, "777", use_umask = FALSE)
```

Alternatively use `system` directly:

```
system('chmod 777 file')
```